# Convert scala Seq[Double] to Java List<Double> in Java

Tags: java, scala

I have been dealing with this problem where I want to convert a Scala `Seq[Double]` to a Java `List<Double>`. Everything I found shows how that is done from Scala, but I couldn't find how to do so from Java.

This is what I have:

```
private void fun(Seq<scala.Double> scalaSeq) {
    List<java.lang.Double> l = JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList(scalaSeq).stream().map(a -> java.lang.Double.valueOf(a.toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

So basically, I am converting the scala `Seq` to a Java `List`, streaming over it and then string converting a Scala `Double` to a Java `Double`. 
I tried using `Double::box` instead but the compilers refused to compile when I tried that. Apparently it takes a `java.lang.Double` ?

I was wondering if there is a more straightforward way of doing this and want to log this for future reference. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Seq<scala.Double>` is *not* going to be useful in Java, as far as I know (and unless it changed in later Scala versions). Instead, a Scala `Seq[Double]` will have type `Seq<Object>` as seen from Java. However, it will actually contain `java.lang.Double` objects, so just "cheating" with

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void fun(Seq<Object> scalaSeq) {
    List<Double> l = (List<Double>) (List<?>) JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList(scalaSeq);
}
```

or

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void fun(Seq<Object> scalaSeq) {
    List<Double> l = JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList((Seq<Double>) (Seq<?>) scalaSeq);
}
```

(all `Double` there are `java.lang.Double`) should work well enough.

Comment: Both approaches give me a compile error: `Inconvertible types; cannot cast java.util.List<java.lang.Object> to java.util.List<java.lang.Double> `. 

However, following up on your suggestion I managed the following:

`JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList(scalaSeq).stream().mapToDouble(a -> Double.valueOf((Double) a)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());` which I find still ugly, but better than my initial approach

Comment: Actually the `Double.valueOf()` is redundant as just casting is sufficient.

Comment: Ah, right, you need to add an intermediate cast to avoid that problem. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
.map(s-> java.lang.Double.parseDouble(s.toString()));
```

Comment: could you please add some explanation about your solution.

Comment: Is it really necessary to round-trip over the string representation?

Comment: I am not sure how using `Double.parseDouble()` is much, if any, different than `Double.valueOf()`. Could you please explain if it is any better ?